# Иконка приложения в трее Win 10

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, gui, windows-10

При добавлении в трей иконки приложения через метод `Shell_NotifyIcon` изображение иконки искажается, независимо от размеров изображений в .ico файле.
Например, когда в .ico имеются изображения 16х16, 24х24, 32х32, то берется 32х32 и даунскейлится до 16 - получаем кашу вместо иконки, если удалить из .ico всё, кроме 16х16, то тоже изображение искажается (размывается).
Как можно побороть эту проблему?

код:

```
memset(&notifyIconData, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
notifyIconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
notifyIconData.hWnd = hWnd;
notifyIconData.uID = IDI_ICON_BALANCED;
notifyIconData.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
notifyIconData.uCallbackMessage = WM_SYSICON;
notifyIconData.hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL),   MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON_BALANCED));
```

Comment: Попробуйте ф-цию [LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) явно указав нужный размер в cxDesired и cyDesired.

Comment: @nick_n_a, данный вариант уже пробовался, для дефолтного скейла (100%) он подходит, однако при выборе 125% или 150% все опять плывет

Comment: А скейл узнать можно? Посмотрев, допустим, высоту трей-окна? И в зависимости от него подставить в cxDesired  нужное значение. Может GetSystemMetrix даст размер...

Comment: @nick_n_a, можно наверное, но зачем так жить) возможно есть какой-то способ, чтобы винда сама доставала нужные изображения и не скейлила их.

Comment: Винда использует  SM_CXICON из GetSystemMetrix  для LoadIcon. Поэтому получите глюк( Т.е. LoadIcon 100% не подходит.

Comment: Возможно это https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx поможет узнать размер